# How do I hide/remove year from datetime query

Tags: datetime

I want to return month - day from my date column. It is set to Datetime format.

I have tried DATENAME, DATEPART, month, day, and year and all of them give me a singular response. I'd like to keep the month and day in the same column. If not I'll find a workaround.

---

2022-01-09

---

01-09

```
Select Cast(created_date as date)Date, 
    [Name],
    count(Name)Total, 
    Cast(Sum([Total_Tax_Exclusive_Price])as Decimal(18,2))Revenue
From DBO.Receipts
Where [name] Like 'Smartfruit Smoothie%'
and [Created_Date] between '2022-09-15' and '2022-12-20'
Group by Cast(created_date as date),Name
```

This query returns

```
Date      |        Name     | Count|Revenue
2022-09-15  Smartfruit Smoothie 10  46.75
2022-09-16  Smartfruit Smoothie 3   14.00
2022-09-17  Smartfruit Smoothie 14  64.75
2022-09-19  Smartfruit Smoothie 10  49.00
2022-09-20  Smartfruit Smoothie 6   29.50
2022-09-21  Smartfruit Smoothie 14  69.75
```

Comment: "datetime column" of *what*?

Comment: datetime is the format of my column 'created_date'.  the datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd. I was hoping just to drop the year off and return 'mm-dd'

Comment: Which DB/SQL is this about?

Comment: sql server management studio